# Why Does Spring-Security Ignore My Log-In-Attempt (Vaadin, Postgres)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, authentication, vaadin

Vaadin has a springboot-security-integration via "LoginForm" by setting `LoginForm.action("login")` which sends the form forward to springboot.

I see the user in my database and I see hibernate making a sql query when trying to login, but the login doesn't work nor does it show me any error or exception to handle.

**What I do:**

- Register a user via `registerUser in UserService.class`
- See Hibernate interacting with postgres via following output in the console:

> Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.app_user_role as
> app_user2_0_, user0_.email as email3_0_, user0_.enabled as
> enabled4_0_, user0_.locked as locked5_0_, user0_.password as
> password6_0_, user0_.username as username7_0_ from public.user user0_
> where user0_.username=?
>
> Hibernate: insert into public.user (app_user_role, email, enabled,
> locked, password, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

- switch to the Login-View
- put in the same credentials I just used to register
- See Hibernate interacting with postgres via following output in the console:

> Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.app_user_role as app_user2_0_, user0_.email as email3_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_0_, user0_.locked as locked5_0_, user0_.password as password6_0_, user0_.username as username7_0_ from public.user user0_ where user0_.username=?

- Get redirected to `localhost:8080/login?error`

Checking via psql I can see that the user is saved in the database with an encrypted password, but I still can't log in using that account. There must be something I am missing - any help would be very appreciated as I've been reading through several documentations now, everyone suggesting something else.

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, Login.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");
        super.configure(web);
    }
}
```

**Login.class** (View (Vaadin))

```
@Route(value = "login")
@AnonymousAllowed
public class Login extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {
    LoginForm loginForm;

    public Login() {
        loginForm = new LoginForm();
        loginForm.setId("login-form");
        loginForm.setAction("login");
        add(loginForm);

        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
        setSizeFull();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
        // inform the user about an authentication error
        if(beforeEnterEvent.getLocation()
                .getQueryParameters()
                .getParameters()
                .containsKey("error")) {
            loginForm.setError(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**UserService.class**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    @Lazy
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND = "User with name %s does not exist!";

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    public void registerUser(User user) throws UsernameAlreadyExistsException {
        try {
            loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
            throw new UsernameAlreadyExistsException();
        } catch(UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(username);
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> {
            System.out.println("Username not found " + username);
            return new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND, username));
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit/Solution:**

Well not even 10 minutes after posting here I have found the answer, despite having struggled with this for almost a whole day now.

When implementing UserDetails in my User.class, the implemented methods `isAccountNonExpired()` and `isCredentialsNonExpired()` by default implementation return `false`. Which ... well, causes the account to be expired. Therefore you can't log in. Sadly I could only see that error-message when finally found the property I need to set for security-debugging.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Comment: Can you please add your own answer?

Comment: Please do not put the solution into the question. Add an answer with the solution. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept that answer.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not even 10 minutes after posting here I have found the answer, despite having struggled with this for almost a whole day now.

When implementing UserDetails in my User.class, the implemented methods `isAccountNonExpired()` and `isCredentialsNonExpired()` by default implementation return false. Which ... well, causes the account to be expired. Therefore you can't log in. Sadly I could only see that error-message when finally found the property I need to set for security-debugging.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```